# Magento price update js configurable products

Tags: php, javascript, magento

In my Magento installation, I have edited the price.html to add in section such as was £X.XX and savings £X.XX.

The problem is that when an option from the drop-down on a configurable product the layout of the price box changes like it is using another template, for example the sections which has savings £X.XX disappears completely.

Does anyone have an idea on how stop it changing the layout or just to update the price and not change anything else in the price file?

Comment: Should the savings value change when the configurable price do ?

Comment: @blmage Yes I would of though the js would of changed the price variable in the price.phtml so everything will be able to stay the same?

Comment: There are no ajax calls or such done when product options are changed, so the price template is not used anymore after the page is loaded. Instead, all the prices are entirely re-computed in JS within `Product.Config` (for configurable products) and `Product.OptionsPrices` (for all kind of varying prices) classes.